# How to use a map which contains String and double values in Struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I want to know How can i pass `HashMap` which contain String and double values from Action to javascript code ?

When i edit some fields with double values, i have a null on those fields, how can i resolve that ?

**Action :**

```
 public String query() {
    Service = new ServiceImpl();
    v = new Vehicule();
    v= Service.getByImmat(im);
    map.put("kilo", v.getKilo()); //double value
    /*SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formats1 = formatter5.format(ss1);*/
    map.put("datepicker", formats1);
    map.put("etat", v.getEtat());//string value
    map.put("capacite_bagages", v.getCapacite_bagage()); //double value
    return "success";
}
```

Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url  : "<s:url action='query'/>",
    dataType : 'json',
    data: { imm : selectedValue},
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(key,value){ 
            $("#"+key).val(value); 
        });
    });
```

**EDIT :**

I want to update some values `(string,Date and double)` ,for this reason I pass those parameters into `map<String,object>` from action to jsp page.

```
public String query() {
        Service = new ServiceImpl();
        v = new Vehicule();
        v= Service.getByImmat(im);
        map.put("kilo", v.getKilo()); //double value
        SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formats1 = formatter5.format(v.getDate());
        map.put("datepicker", formats1);
        map.put("etat", v.getEtat());//string value
        map.put("capacite_bagages", v.getCapacite_bagage()); //double value
        return "success";
    }
```

I show it in my jsp,I edit it in my jsp page,but when I want to save the result,  double value take a NAN !! :

```
public String modifiervehicule () {

        Service = new ServiceImpl();
        v= new Vehicule();
        v = vehiculeService.getVehiculeByImmat(immatricul);
        v.setKilo((Double)getKilo());
        v.setDate((Date)getDate());
        v.setEtat(getEtat());
        v.setCapacite_bagage((Double)getCapacite_bagages());

        v = Service.update(v);
        return "success";

    }
```

kilo field (double) has a null value after editing, but if I edit it with Integer value it will not have a null value,

I think because `public double getkilo()` should return a double not object that i pass in the map !!)

**EDIT 2 :**

**jsp :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    {

      $('#imm').change(function()
        {


          var selectedValue = $('#imm').val();
            if ($.trim(selectedValue).length > 0) 
             {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url  : "<s:url action='query'/>",
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: { imm : selectedValue},
                    success: function(result){                                                                                     
                        $.each(result, function(key,value)
                        {                    


                                $("#"+key).val(value);

                                                            } );                                
    });
</script>

<s:form  cssStyle="border:0;" validate="true" action="modifiervehicule" namespace="/" >
<s:select  id="imm" label="immatriculation" list="immatriculs" name="immatricul"></s:select>
<s:textfield id="kilo"  name="kil" label="kilometrage" size="15" ></s:textfield>
<s:textfield  id="etat" name="etat" label="etat" size="15" ></s:textfield>
 <s:textfield  id="datepicker" name="date" label="date"  size="15" ></s:textfield> 
<s:textfield id="capacite_bagages" name="capacite_bagages" label="capacité de bagages" size="15"></s:textfield>

<s:submit  style="height:30px; width:125px" name="Valider" value="Valider"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

**`Struts.xml`**

```
<action name="query" class="action.Gestion" method="query">
    <result name="success" type="json" >
        <param name="root">map</param>

    </result>

</action>
```

Comment: Your code has some pieces missing ( Service =, and so on).  What is map ? Which value do the double variables have ? What is printed on page ?

Comment: private Service Service; // service connected to database with hibernate
private Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `map` to map objects instead of strings. For example

```
Map<String, Object> map= new HashMap<>();
```

Now you have to put objects inside it, if the value is `null` it will keep the value that you can get after JSON result is returned by the `success` handler. See also 
[how to exclude properties with `null` values from the JSON result](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-Excludingpropertieswithnullvalues).

Comment: i still have a null values !

Comment: I want to update some values (string,Integer and double) ,for this reason I pass those parameters into map<String,object> from action to jsp page.
I show it in my jsp,I edit it, but when I want to save the result, all double values take a NAN !!

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, could you update your question?

Comment: I don't know how actions are mapped to the JSP, so post the `struts.xml`. Also format the code with indentation.

Comment: I post the struts.xml

Comment: I think that a service returns `null`, post the JSON.